# How i can implement error validation message in React Form with Zod Schema using discrimination union?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zod, react-forms

I'm working on a form using `react-form hooks` and using `zod` for validation. I'm using zod `discriminationUnion` to dynamically show different fields based on a selection named `modes` with three options: FCL, LCL, and BULK.
[image: Demo]
I have 3 zod schemas for `FCL`, `LCL`, and `BULK`, and they also share common fields like `from`, `to`, `comment`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, and more. 
**Zod Schema**:

```
// Import the 'z' library, which is used for schema validation.
import * as z from "zod";

// Define a schema for Full Container Load (FCL) mode.
const fclSchema = z.object({
  from: z.object({
    address: z.string(),
    latitude: z.number().min(-90).max(90),
    longitude: z.number().min(-180).max(180),
  }),
  to: z.object({
    address: z.string(),
    latitude: z.number().min(-90).max(90),
    longitude: z.number().min(-180).max(180),
  }),
  modes: z.literal('FCL'), // Specifies the mode as 'FCL'.
  f_container_type: z.enum(["20", "40", "40HC"]), // Specifies container types.
  f_quantity: z.coerce.number().min(1).max(32767),
  f_weight: z.coerce.number(),
  f_unit: z.enum(["kg", "lbs"]),
  comment: z.string().min(3).max(160).optional(), // Optional comment.
  hsn: z.enum(["1", "2", "3"]), // HSN enum.
  date: z.date(), // Date field.
  ico: z.enum(["FCA", "FOB", "CFR", "DDU", "DAP", "DDP"]), // ICO enum.
  insurance: z.boolean(),
  custom: z.boolean(),
  firstName: z.string().min(3).max(18), // First name validation.
  lastName: z.string().min(3).max(18), // Last name validation.
  phone: z.string().min(10).max(15), // Phone number validation.
  email: z.string().email(), // Email validation.
  company: z.string().min(3).max(18), // Company name validation.
});

// Define a schema for Less than Container Load (LCL) mode.
const lclSchema = z.object({
  from: z.object({
    address: z.string(),
    latitude: z.number().min(-90).max(90),
    longitude: z.number().min(-180).max(180),
  }),
  to: z.object({
    address: z.string(),
    latitude: z.number().min(-90).max(90),
    longitude: z.number().min(-180).max(180),
  }),
  modes: z.literal('LCL'), // Specifies the mode as 'LCL'.
  l_container_type: z.enum(["pallete", "boxes", "package", "bag"]), // Container types.
  l_load: z.array(
    z.object({
      l_wid: z.coerce.number().nullish(),
      l_hgt: z.coerce.number().nullish(),
      l_lgt: z.coerce.number().nullish(),
      l_volume_unit: z.enum(["cm", "in"]),
      l_quantity: z.coerce.number().nullish(),
      l_weight: z.coerce.number().nullish(),
      l_weight_unit: z.enum(["kg", "lbs"]),
    })
  ).refine(data => data.every(load => load.l_quantity !== null && load.l_quantity !== undefined && load.l_quantity >= 1), {
    message: 'Quantity must be at least 1',
    path: ['l_load', 'l_quantity'], // Validation for load quantity.
  }),
  comment: z.string().min(3).max(160), // Comment validation.
  hsn: z.enum(["1", "2", "3"]), // HSN enum.
  date: z.date(), // Date field.
  ico: z.enum(["FCA", "FOB", "CFR", "DDU", "DAP", "DDP"]), // ICO enum.
  insurance: z.boolean(),
  custom: z.boolean(),
  firstName: z.string().min(1).max(18), // First name validation.
  lastName: z.string().min(1).max(18), // Last name validation.
  phone: z.string().min(10).max(14), // Phone number validation.
  email: z.string().email(), // Email validation.
  company: z.string().min(1).max(18), // Company name validation.
});

// Define a schema for Bulk mode.
const bulkSchema = z.object({
  from: z.object({
    address: z.string(),
    latitude: z.number().min(-90).max(90),
    longitude: z.number().min(-180).max(180),
  }),
  to: z.object({
    address: z.string(),
    latitude: z.number().min(-90).max(90),
    longitude: z.number().min(-180).max(180),
  }),
  modes: z.literal('BULK'), // Specifies the mode as 'BULK'.
  b_type: z.enum([
    "GC",
    "RC",
    "DG",
    "OOG",
    "BC",
    "C",
    "P/AC",
    "P/CT",
    "P/CC",
    "P/GC",
    "S/HL",
    "S/L",
    "S/R",
    "S/Ro",
    "S/WC",
  ]),
  b_load: z.array(
    z.object({
      b_wid: z.coerce.number().nullish(),
      b_hgt: z.coerce.number().nullish(),
      b_lgt: z.coerce.number().nullish(),
      b_volume_unit: z.enum(["cm", "in"]),
      b_quantity: z.coerce.number().nullish(),
      b_weight: z.coerce.number().nullish(),
      b_weight_unit: z.enum(["kg", "lbs"]),
    })
  ),
  b_loading_rate: z.coerce.number(),
  b_loading_unit: z.enum(["kg/day", "lbs/day"]),
  b_discharge_rate: z.coerce.number(),
  b_discharge_unit: z.enum(["kg/day", "lbs/day"]),
  comment: z.string().min(3).max(160), // Comment validation.
  hsn: z.enum(["1", "2", "3"]), // HSN enum.
  date: z.date(), // Date field.
  ico: z.enum(["FCA", "FOB", "CFR", "DDU", "DAP", "DDP"]), // ICO enum.
  insurance: z.boolean(),
  custom: z.boolean(),
  firstName: z.string().min(1).max(18), // First name validation.
  lastName: z.string().min(1).max(18), // Last name validation.
  phone: z.string().min(10).max(24), // Phone number validation.
  email: z.string().email(), // Email validation.
  company: z.string().min(1).max(18), // Company name validation.
});

// Create a discriminated union schema that selects the appropriate mode schema based on the 'modes' field.
export const profileFormSchema = z.discriminatedUnion("modes", [
  fclSchema,
  lclSchema,
  bulkSchema,
]);
```

**the Problem** is all the common elements are showing error messages just fine. However, when it comes to the dynamic element, using `{errors.f_quantity && <span className="text-red-500">{errors.f_quantity.message}</span>`} is causing an error.

```
Property 'f_quantity' does not exist on type 'FieldErrors<{ from: { address: string; latitude: number; longitude: number; }; date: Date; custom: boolean; to: { address: string; latitude: number; longitude: number; }; modes: "FCL"; f_container_type: "20" | ... 1 more ... | "40HC"; ... 11 more ...; comment?: string | undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; }>'.
  Property 'f_quantity' does not exist on type 'Partial<FieldErrorsImpl<{ from: { address: string; latitude: number; longitude: number; }; date: Date; custom: boolean; to: { address: string; latitude: number; longitude: number; }; modes: "LCL"; comment: string; ... 9 more ...; l_load: { ...; }[]; }>> & { ...; }'.ts(2339)
```

Below code this displays dynamic element when `mode`===`FCL` here im using watch hook to monitor `mode`selection element( `const watchMode = watch("modes");`)

**Code**(i have marked error lines below):

```
  {/* SELECT==FCL */}
              {watchMode === "FCL" && (
                <div>
                  <div className="sm:flex sm:space-x-4 ">
                    <div className="sm:w-1/2 mt-5">
                      <Label className="mb-2">Container type</Label>
                      <Controller
                        name="f_container_type"
                        control={control} 
                        render={({ field }) => (
                          <Select
                            value={field.value}
                            onValueChange={field.onChange}
                          >
                            <SelectTrigger>
                              <SelectValue placeholder="Container type" />
                            </SelectTrigger>
                            <SelectContent>
                              <SelectItem value="20">20' Standard</SelectItem>
                              <SelectItem value="40">40' Standard</SelectItem>
                              <SelectItem value="40HC">
                                40' High cube
                              </SelectItem>
                            </SelectContent>
                          </Select>
                        )}
                      />
                      
                    </div>
                    <div className="sm:w-1/2 mt-5">
                      <Label className="mb-2">Quantity</Label>
                      <Input
                        type="number"
                        placeholder="Enter the Quantity"
                        {...register("f_quantity")}
                      />
//HERE----------------------------------------------->
                     {errors.f_quantity && <span className="text-red-500">{errors.f_quantity.message}</span>}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="sm:w-1/2 mt-5">
                    <Label className="mb-2">Weight</Label>

                    <div className="relative max-w-[400px]">
                      <Input
                        type="number"
                        className="py-3 px-4 pr-16 block w-full border-none shadow-sm rounded-md text-sm"
                        placeholder="Enter the Weight"
                        {...register("f_weight")}
                       
                      /> 
//HERE-------------------------------------------------------------------------->
                      {errors.f_weight && <span className="text-red-500">{errors.f_weight.message}</span>}
                      <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center  z-20 pr-4">
                        <Controller
                          name="f_unit"
                          control={control} // make sure to define 'control' in your useForm hook
                          defaultValue="kg"
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <Select
                              value={field.value}
                              onValueChange={field.onChange}
                            >
                              <SelectTrigger className=" border-none text-">
                                <SelectValue />
                              </SelectTrigger>
                              <SelectContent>
                                <SelectItem value="kg">KG</SelectItem>
                                <SelectItem value="lbs">LBS</SelectItem>
                              </SelectContent>
                            </Select>
                          )}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
```

**codesandbox** 
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/github/Amith-AG/discriminatedunion_react_form/tree/master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typescript, you cannot type-guard with different references. so you have to check `mode` value on `errors` object itself.

```
if(errors.mode === "FCL") {
    errors.f_quantity // no errors
}
```

if you really want to use `watch` function, you can check both together

```
{watchMode === "FCL" && errors.mode === "FCL" && (
   errors.f_quantity // no errors, again :)
)}
```

**Edit:**

I Checked your code and looks like the errors object does not hold the original value and only holds data about the error.

So, to solve the issue you have, we can create a type-guard function to check if the value is what we want. here is how:

```
const isModeOf = <TMode extends FormValues["modes"]>(err: typeof errors, mode: TMode): err is FieldErrors<Extract<FormValues, {modes: TMode}>> => {
   return watchMode === mode
  }

// usage
<>
    {isModeOf(errors, "FCL") && <>
        {errors.f_quantity // no errors }
    </>}
</>
```

you can see the code at my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/priceless-sid-3rpzqw?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A132%2C44)

If you want to know more type guard functions, you can read from [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Comment: thanks for replying shows same error. I found the answer for it,we have to use `(errors as any).f_quantity` in my case.

Comment: @AmithAG I'm pretty sure there is a better solution for that. could you give me this part of your source code? like in code-sandbox?

Comment: sure here is the link https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/github/Amith-AG/discriminatedunion_react_form/tree/master

Comment: @AmithAG just updated the answer :)

Comment: i didnt see any changes

Comment: @AmithAG that's weird! the codesandbox link that I attached works fine. did you also import `FieldErrors` type?

Comment: oh my bad i didnt see the edited answer

Comment: What is the difference using `(error as any)` and `type gaurd function` which appears to have more line of code?

Comment: @AmithAG best practice and type safety. You should avoid using type `any` as much as possible. if we use the type `any`, then what is the point of using typescript? :)

Comment: @AmithAg That code sandbox demonstration worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript checks the types of variable at compile time only not in runtime.In my case,I have a form with different field(such as `f_quantity`,`f_weight`,`b_load`,`l_load`...etc) and also same fields as well(such as `from`,`to`,`comment`,`firstName`...ect).the `f_quantity` property is only valid when the modes field is `FCL`. When modes is `LCL` or `BULK`, the f_quantity property does not exist according to my schema definitions.
**Solution:**
`(errors as any).f_quantity` tells TypeScript to treat errors as having any type, which bypasses the type checking for f_quantity.
[image: Output:when 0 it shows error message as intended]